# Select <select> <option> from alternate select using jQuery, Javascript, or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I needed help regarding selection copying, as I know nothing about it. Here's my problem: I need to select a state from one select, and then have it automatically select the same state in another select. But my values are different for each select, as the info will be processed to the server (otherwise, there wouldn't be a problem, because I wouldn't need to copy from one select to the other). Here is my format:

```
<select name="state" size="1" id="stateSelect">
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<select>

<select name="state" size="1" id="stateSelect2">
<option class="AL" value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
</select>
```

And this is my current jQuery that I've pieced together from all over the internet (that obviously doesn't work):

```
$(function(){
    $("select[name*='state']").change(function(){
        $("#stateSelect2").children(':selected').hasClass( $("#stateSelect").val() )
    })
})
```

So, what I need is to be able to do is copy the value selected by "stateSelect", and select the value of "stateSelect2" by the class that has the value of the selected option of "stateSelect". I don't know how easy or hard this is to do, but I sure would appreciate any and all help with this issue. if you use JSFiddle, bonus points to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#stateSelect').on('change', function(){
    var v = $(this).val();
    $('#stateSelect2 .'+v).prop('selected', true);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dipser/9ca0eL1d/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should suffice:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#stateSelect').on('change', function(){

        var val = $(this).val();

        if(val.length > 0 && $('#stateSelect2 option.' + val).length > 0) {

            $('#stateSelect2 option.' + val).attr('selected', 'selected');
            // could also use .prop() here instead of attr
            // which would be .prop('selected', true);
        }
    });
});
```

The if statement makes sure that the selected `option` has a value and **also** exists in the second `select`.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6hq1cyhx/)